# LLVM bitcode does not find function

Tags: function, llvm

I went forward and compiled an existing c code via `llvm-gcc -emit-llvm -c` to llvm bitcode. The c program consisted of four modules which I built to one big bitcode each via `llvm-ld`. Then I tried to merge these 4 bitcode files to one via `llvm-ld GE.bc GA.bc SD.bc SH.bc -o prog` which works without complaint.
Trying to execute the bitcode though it complains:
*LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'myFunction' which could not be resolved!*

The thing is *myFunction* should be defined in SD.bc and used also in GA.bc.
But it's not to find in SD.bc - does llvm-ld skip all definitions that are not used!?

My OS is Linux and I use llvm version 2.6.

Comment: Is it really a declaration in GA.bc and a definition is in SD.bc? What `llvm-dis` shows? You have to give bitcode files and libraries to `llvm-ld` in a dependency order.

Comment: in file _SD1.bc_ there is `define void @myFunction(i32 %exitCode) nounwind {` but in _SD.bc_ there is no such line!

Comment: Seems like *-link-as-library* is not enough to preserve the symbols. When also specifying option *-disable-opt* it preserves the function. Very confusing.

Comment: you can apply the optimisations later, using `opt`.

Answer (score 1):

As a note llvm is on version 2.9 with 3.0 approaching. You should really upgrade.

Comment: Agree. LLVM is changing rapidly  - IMHO , In great direction :).